# Analysis of a tree generated by BFS

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search

I thought about asking this question in the Mathexchange, but it is less about calculation and yes/no, but more about computer science related algorithm, so I am asking it here.

In BFS algorithm, it is possible to mark each level of traversal as layers. For example, if `s` is the starting vertice, vertices in any single layer should all have same distance to `s`. This is the one of the most basic characteristic of BFS search algorithm.

Assume that there are i layers, and a tree generated by BFS algorithm to be called `T`, and the graph to be called `G`. This means that the maximum distance between any 2 nodes in `T` would be `i`. (probably one from the starting layer, and one from the bottom layer)

Using that property, **how can I prove that there exists a vertex `a` in `G` such that its degree would be at most `6*|V|/i` ?**

I thought since any vertex `u` in Layer `L_j` have edges connected to the vertices in layer `L_j-1` and `L_j+1`, showing the existence of 3 consequent layers with total of at most `6|V|/i` vertices. would help.

But the thing is that I know the goal, but I do not know how to approach it.

Comment: are you sure the questions is well formulated? a [Complete graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) of n vertices has n-1 degree.

Comment: Yes, so any vertex in the n-complete graph would have n-1 degree which is less than 6*n/i where `i` in complete graph would be 1 in any case. (Because BFS in complete graph will end in a single iteration)

Comment: is `G` simple? [can there be more then 1 edge between 2 vertices? can there be self loops?]

Comment: I guess G is an undirected simple graph. If G is not a simple graph, than 100 edges between 2 vertices will make them to have a degree of 100, which exceeds 6*(2)/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach should probably be: Take triplets of layers (eg. [1,2,3], [4,5,6]...). There are `i/3` of them and they are disjoint. Together, they have `V` vertices, which means there must be a triplet with `<= V/(i/3)` of them (otherwise ... count it). However, this approach leads to at most `3V/i` degree.

Maybe the `i` should be the diameter (I'll call it `m` as Maximum distance between two vertices. I'm confused by your statement

> the maximum distance between any 2 nodes in T would be i.

which is not true - for some vertices you must go up then down). Then, `m` would be `<= 2*i` which leads to vertices with degree at most `6V/m`.

Comment: @chac: BFS doesn't. But how do you go from a leaf to a different leaf in a tree? That makes the distance.

Comment: Hi @palecek , Yes, I think the maximum distance between any 2 nodes can be <= 2*i like you said. This answer is simply amazing. Thanks!